# Espresso & Mapbox IdlingResource : need advice

Tags: automated-tests, android-espresso, mapbox-android

I am looking for some advices in order to create an idling resource to make my espresso tests wait when the map is not idling.
During tests, we have a lot of camera movements, zooms etc so a lot of tiles are downloaded and old devices are quite solicited. Since our backend can be slow sometimes, some of our espresso tests are failing.

Our project is using `mapbox 5.1.3` (we can't upgrade actually) so i have based my approach on the `addOnMapChangedListener` callbacks but it does not seem to work properly. I can still see that espresso is continuing the tests while the map is not yet ready...

So, here is what i have implemented so far in order to handle map/tiles loadings :

```
class MapboxIdlingResource(mapview: MapView) : IdlingResource {
    private var mapbox: MapboxMap? = null
    private var resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback? = null
    private var isIdle = true
    init {
        mapview.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->
            this.mapbox = mapboxMap
            mapview.addOnMapChangedListener { change ->
                when (change) {
                    MapView.DID_FAIL_LOADING_MAP,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_LOADING_MAP,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_LOADING_STYLE,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_RENDERING_FRAME,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_RENDERING_FRAME_FULLY_RENDERED,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_RENDERING_MAP,
                    MapView.DID_FINISH_RENDERING_MAP_FULLY_RENDERED,
                    MapView.SOURCE_DID_CHANGE,
                    MapView.REGION_DID_CHANGE,
                    MapView.REGION_DID_CHANGE_ANIMATED -> setIdle()

                    MapView.REGION_IS_CHANGING,
                    MapView.REGION_WILL_CHANGE,
                    MapView.REGION_WILL_CHANGE_ANIMATED,
                    MapView.WILL_START_LOADING_MAP,
                    MapView.WILL_START_RENDERING_FRAME,
                    MapView.WILL_START_RENDERING_MAP -> waitForSomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        return javaClass.simpleName
    }

    override fun isIdleNow(): Boolean {
        return isIdle
    }

    override fun registerIdleTransitionCallback(resourceCallback: IdlingResource.ResourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback
    }

    private fun waitForSomething(mapEvent: Int) {
        isIdle = false
    }

    private fun setIdle(mapEvent: Int) {
        isIdle = true
        resourceCallback?.onTransitionToIdle()
    }
}
```

Could you tell me if the approach is right ? Am I missing something ?
Thank you for your help.